# Spring Batch shall wait for service to get back online

Tags: web-services, rest, spring-batch

I have a Spring Batch application which receives a CSV file and writes to a webservice.

I am looking for a way to pause the batch execution if the webservice is offline and resume it when it's back on.

Have anyone run into the same situation? Any advice is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking seconds or hours/days?

Comment: Seconds, maybe minutes, the whole solution is scalable and outages should not last too long. I am already returning an error to the user but maybe this can be improved in short outages.

Comment: I ask because you can handle short interruptions via retry functionality.  However, if the outage would be greater and you'd want to be able to actually stop the job, you'd need to do some custom development to handle that.